# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty x\cdot e^{-n^2x-\frac{\pi^2}{x}(k^2+j^2)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How could the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x\cdot e^{-n^2x-\frac{\pi^2}{x}(k^2+j^2)}\, dx$$
be evaluated? I know the similar looking integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-n^2x-\frac{\pi^2}{4x}(k^2+j^2)}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
has the solution:
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n}\,e^{-\pi n\sqrt{k^2+j^2}}$$
and thanks to [How does one derive the following formula of integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3323655/how-does-one-derive-the-following-formula-of-integration) I also know how this is derived, but I'm not able to use the tricks mentioned in there to solve the upper integral. What does the upper integral evaluate to?

Comment: In this case, it might be easier to write it as $\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-Ax-B/x}$ where $A,B$ are positive. The exact expression for $A=n^2,B=\pi^2(k^2+j^2)$ isn't relevant. In the second case, you'd have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-Ax-B/(4x)}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{A}}e^{-\sqrt{AB}}$$

Comment: If $$f(A,B)=\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-Ax-B/x}\,dx$$ then you can do substitutions $u=Ax$ to get $f(A,B)=\frac{1}{A^2}f(1,AB)$ and $u=x/B$ to get $f(A,B)=B^2 f(AB,1).$ Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha gives:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ax-b/x}\,dx =\frac{2b}{a}K_2(2\sqrt{ab})$$ where $K_2$ is a "[modified Bessel function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)." But $K_2$'s definition is fairly messy.

For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) first defines $$I_\alpha(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}$$

Then $$K_2(x)=\frac{\pi}2\lim_{\alpha\to 2} \frac{I_{-\alpha}(x)-I_{\alpha}(x)}{\sin \pi\alpha}$$

Comment: Your answer agrees with mine.  The three-term recurrence writes $K_2$ in terms of $K_1$ and $K_0$.

Comment: Thanks! And I agree the documentation and definition of the modified Bessel function by wolfram and by wikipedia is quite messy, but better than nothing I guess

Answer (score 0):

Maple does this in terms of modified [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the second kind.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty }\!x{{\rm e}^{-{a}^{2}x-{\frac {{b}^{2}}{x}}}}
\,{\rm d}x
=
\frac{2b^2}{a^2} {{{\rm K}_{0}\left(2\,ab\right)}
}
+\frac{2b}{a^3}\,{{{\rm K}_{1}\left(2\,ab\right)}}
$$

Comment: Interestingly, Wolfram Alpha gives it in terms of $K_2.$ In your notation, $\frac{2b^2}{a^2}K_2(2ab).$